# Split and get total count from string

Tags: c#, linq

I have a string `CHF,2$DVC,1$PP,4` and i want result as this

List

```
     CHF
     DVC
     PP
```

Sum: `7`

i can do it by spliting with '$', then apply foreach loop then again split with ',' and apply foreach loop.

On google i found that 
if i had string like `string myString = "1,2,4,8,16";`
the i can get the sum with `.Sum(x => int.Parse(x))` but don't know how to implement in my case

Can anybody tell me how can i get desired result using linq without loop as i am new in linq

Comment: Can you explain how you come to a sum of 7? I am counting 8 characters but thats only a guess

Comment: @VahidNateghi you are right

Comment: you should write this down in your question.  For me it was not clear you want the numbers, because your List contained 3 sets of letters.

Comment: yes but 3 sets of letters sum is 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try something like this

```
var t = "CHF,2$DVC,1$PP,4".Split('$').Select(s=>s.Split(','))
var list = t.Select(i=>i[0]).ToList();
var sum = t.Sum(i=>int.Parse(i[1]));
```

Comment: I love intuitive variable names... :)

Comment: @gehho yep, but quickly :-)

Comment: @Grundy: Thanks that really quick and exactly i want :)